# Canadian PPL as an American?

Tags: medical, canada

I am an American hobbyist pilot who had been flying for years as a LSA pilot. Recently, I started training for my PPL and applied for medical. Sadly, it is likely my Class 3 will be rejected to past history with anxiety (long since resolved, and been off meds for years).

I live close to the Canadian border… how hard would it be to get a Canadian PPL? My cursory reading of their requirements suggests that all that is required for medical is a thorough physical (which shouldn’t be an issue for me). I have the skills and hours to checkride today if I had to.

Is this a possibility? If so, how long would it take?

Comment: Gotta love the FAA's enlightened attitude toward these issues.

Comment: Have you actually submitted the medical application to the FAA? If not, don't! If you have, there might be a way to cancel it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Someone As far as the FAA is concerned, you can even submit it to MedXPress and as long as you haven't started a physical with an AME you haven't started an application.

Comment: @MarcusAurelius Long-since resolved anxiety is not a deal-breaker. If you haven't seen an AME yet, do some research before doing so! Depending on the exact details of your medical records (which you certainly should not post here) it *may* be possible for you to be issued on the spot. But you will certainly be deferred if you go in unprepared. I highly recommend discussing your specific case with an AME before actually going into the physical. If you already have been deferred, a special issuance is a possibility. How much time and effort this would take depends again on your medical details.